# Get IStorage from externaly created file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I`m currently developing an editor plug-in in Eclipse Neon. Everything works perfectly except from opening files with the editor, which were not created inside of the current Eclipse project but manually in a folder outside of the workspace (e.g. Documents).

In my implementation, I need the `IStorage` of every file I want to open. My current code looks like this:

```
public static IStorage getStorage(IEditorInput editorInput) {
    if (editorInput instanceof IStorageEditorInput) {
      try {
        return ((IStorageEditorInput) editorInput).getStorage();
      }
      catch (CoreException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
    else if (editorInput instanceof FileStoreEditorInput) {
      try {
        IURIEditorInput uriInput = (IURIEditorInput)editorInput;
        URI uri = uriInput.getURI();
        File file = new File(uri);
        return ((IStorageEditorInput) editorInput).getStorage(); // How to get the IStorage
      }
      catch (CoreException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown IEditorInput implementation");
    }
  }
```

The important case is if the `editorInput` is an instance of `FileStoreEditorInput`, which is handled in the second if. Currently, I get a file out of it, but I don't know how to get the `IStorage` from the file or from the `FileStoreEditorInput` itself.

Comment: just read your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware that there is a way to get an `IStorage` for a `FileStoreEditorInput`. Except you could try and see if `editorInput.getAdapter( IStorage.class )` returns something useful.

However, you can implement the `IStorage` interface yourself. For example:

```java
class FileStorage implements IStorage {
  private final FileStoreEditorInput editorInput;

  FileStorage( FileStoreEditorInput editorInput ) {
    this.editorInput = editorInput;
  }

  @Override
  public <T> T getAdapter( Class<T> adapter ) {
    return Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter( this, adapter );
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isReadOnly() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return editorInput.getName();
  }

  @Override
  public IPath getFullPath() {
    return new Path( URIUtil.toFile( editorInput.getURI() ).getAbsolutePath() );
  }

  @Override
  public InputStream getContents() {
    try {
      return editorInput.getURI().toURL().openStream();
    } catch( IOException e ) {
      throw new UncheckedIOException( e );
    }
  }
}
```